# How to use Solrj annotations to index Lat/Long

Tags: solr, geospatial, solrj

I have an object that I want to add to my Solr server that I've annotated using solrj's @Field annotation, but I can't find any documentation about what Java data type to use for Solr's **location** type.  Here is my Bean I want to add:

```
@Field
private UUID id;
@Field
LatLonType location; // what should the Java data type of this field be???
@Field
private EventType eventType;
@Field
private int maxCapacity;
@Field
private int minCapacity;
@Field
private double price;
@Field
private Date startDate;
@Field
private Date endDate;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate type on Java side is a simple `String` with both the lat and lon separated by a comma, e.g. `"1.2,3.4"`.

Comment: I know that's how it's created in XML, JSON, etc.  But, if I have gone through the trouble of creating a Java object I want to use a data type that makes working with lat/long convenient.  A concatenated string is not that.  Sounds like SolrJ hasn't thought about that?  True or False?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know anything that makes it more convenient. I guess you might want something like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1945 which is unresolved for 2 years ...

Answer (score 3):

The best solution to the problem is if you want to use addBean() method(s) you'd create a property on the object and annotate that like so:

```
public class MyBean {

   private double latitude;
   private double longitude;

   public String getLocation() {
      return latitude + "," + longitude;
   }

   @Field
   public void setLocation( String value ) {
      String[] split = value.split(",");
      latitude = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
      longitude = Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
   }
}
```